# How to pass env variable as parameter value when reverse shell to container

Tags: linux, bash, kubernetes, openshift

I have been searching but I cannot find answer to my question.

What I am trying to do is to connect to remote shell of openshift container and create db dump, which works if i put username,password and db name by hand (real values).

I wish to execute this command to access env variables: (this command later will be part of bigger script)

```
 oc rsh mon-rs-nr-0 mongodump --host=rs/mon-rs-nr-0.mon-rs-nr.xxx.svc.cluster.local,mon-rs-nr-1.xxx.svc.cluster.local,mon-rs-nr-2.mon-rs-nr.xxx.svc.cluster.local --username=$MONGODB_USER --password=$MONGODB_PASSWORD --authenticationDatabase=$MONGODB_DATABASE
```

But it is not working, I also tried different versions with echo etc. (env vars are not replaced to they values). Env vars are present inside container.

When I try

```
oc rsh mon-rs-nr-0 echo "$MONGODB_PASSWORD"
```

I recieve

```
$MONGODB_PASSWORD
```

But when i firstly connect to container and then execute command:

```
C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop>oc rsh mon-rs-nr-0
$ echo "$MONGODB_PASSWORD"
mAYXXXXXXXXXXX
```

It works. However I need to use it in a way I presented at the top, do somebody know workaround?

Comment: Minor detail: `rsh` stands for "remote shell", not "reverse shell".

Comment: Does escaping the dollar like this: `oc rsh mon-rs-nr-0 echo "\$MONGODB_PASSWORD"` work?

Comment: No, adding "\" dosent work, tried it. The result is \$MONGODB_PASSWORD.

Comment: Maybe using -- before the command would help. k8s has actually already deprecated to do it without. Also to escape you use double $$ but I dont think it would help. `oc rsh mon-rs-nr-0 -- echo "$MONGODB_PASSWORD"`

Comment: What about `oc rsh mon-rs-nr-0 bash -c "echo \$MONGODB_PASSWORD"`? (try without the slash also)

Comment: If after executing `oc rsh mon-rs-nr-0 echo "$MONGODB_PASSWORD"` with `bash` you "_receive_" `$MONGODB_PASSWORD` (whatever "_receive_" means) I see only one possible reason: the value of the `MONGODB_PASSWORD` variable is itself `$MONGODB_PASSWORD`. I suggest to 1) check the values of these variables (type `echo "$VARIABLE_NAME"` in your terminal) 2) double-quote all your variable expansions (`--password="$MONGODB_PASSWORD"` instead of `--password=$MONGODB_PASSWORD`).

Comment: @msaw328 Thanks! now it is working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @msaw328 comment here is solution:

```
C:\Users\xxx\Desktop>oc rsh mon-rs-nr-0  bash -c "mongodump --host=rs/mon-rs-nr-0.mon-rs-nr.xxx.svc.cluster.local,mon-rs-nr-1.mon-rs-nr.xxx.svc.cluster.local,mon-rs-nr-2.mon-rs-nr.xxx.svc.cluster.local --username=$MONGODB_USER --password=$MONGODB_PASSWORD --authenticationDatabase=$MONGODB_DATABASE"
```

Output:

```
Defaulted container "mongodb" out of: mongodb, mongodb-sidecar, mongodb-exporter

2021-08-20T11:01:12.268+0000    writing xxx.yyy to
2021-08-20T11:01:12.269+0000    writing xxx.ccc to
2021-08-20T11:01:12.269+0000    writing xxx.ddd to
2021-08-20T11:01:12.269+0000    writing xxx.eee to
2021-08-20T11:01:12.339+0000    done dumping xxx.eee (11 documents)
2021-08-20T11:01:12.339+0000    writing xxx.zzz to
2021-08-20T11:01:12.340+0000    done dumping xxx.ccc (24 documents)
2021-08-20T11:01:12.340+0000    writing xxx.bbb to
2021-08-20T11:01:12.340+0000    done dumping xxx.ddd (24 documents)
2021-08-20T11:01:12.340+0000    writing xxx.fff to
2021-08-20T11:01:12.436+0000    done dumping xxx.yyy (1000 documents)
2021-08-20T11:01:12.436+0000    writing xxx.ggg to
2021-08-20T11:01:12.436+0000    done dumping xxx.bbb (3 documents)
2021-08-20T11:01:12.437+0000    writing xxx.aaa to
2021-08-20T11:01:12.441+0000    done dumping xxx.fff (0 documents)
2021-08-20T11:01:12.441+0000    done dumping xxx.zzz (3 documents)
2021-08-20T11:01:12.447+0000    done dumping xxx.aaa(0 documents)
2021-08-20T11:01:12.449+0000    done dumping xxx.ggg (0 documents)
```

Comment: That didnt work for me in k8s with a container that has no bash but sh. Using `-- sh -c "echo $MY_VAR"`